# How to set virtual host for specific files?

Tags: php, yii, virtualhost

I am developing an application in Yii 1.1

I want to make separate both `frontend` and `backend`. Doc here : [Yii 1.1: Organize directories for applications with front-end and back-end using WebApplicationEnd behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior/)

I have two files in my root `index.php` and `admin.php`

I want to `index.php` file access through `frontend.dev` and `admin.php` file access through `backend.dev`

Code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName frontend.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName backend.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . admin.php
        DirectoryIndex admin.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I opened `http://backend.dev` then this is working fine. My default `admin.php` page working which set in virtual DirectoryIndex. But when I access any other controller and action like `http://backend.dev/post/test` this URL is accessing `index.php` file. How to manage it?

Please help

***EDIT:***

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Make the backend accessible via url: http://site/backend.
RewriteRule ^admin admin.php

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php.
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: i think it would be better to put your admin.php under a directory called admin/backend it will resolve the issue.

Comment: @YunusSaha There is no directory called admin or backend.

Comment: do you have .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes I have .htaccesss file

Comment: can you put your .htaccess file content to the question?

Comment: @YunusSaha Updated my question. Could you please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160606/discussion-between-developer-and-yunus-saha).

Answer (score 0):

the following can go into your vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName frontend.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName backend.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the following can go into your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frontend.dev
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^backend.dev
RewriteRule ^(.*) admin.php [L]
```

notice the
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frontend.dev`
and
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^backend.dev`

this will correctly forward the request of the domains to its respective files.